# Rare segmentation fault during object creation with new

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, java-native-interface

In a Java application, I use JNI to call several C++ methods. One of the methods creates an object that has to persist after the method finished and that is used in other method calls. To this end, I create a pointer of the object, which I return to Java as a reference for later access (note: the Java class implements `Closable` and in the `close` method, I call a method to delete the object).

However, in rare cases, approximately after 50.000 calls, the C++ code throws a segmentation fault. Based on the content of the log file, only a few lines of code are suspicious to be the source of error (they between the last printed log message and the next one):

```
MyObject* handle = new MyObject(some_vector, shared_ptr1, shared_ptr2);
handles.insert(handle); // handles is a std::set
jlong handleId = (jlong) handle;
```

I'd like to know whether there is a possible issue here apart from the fact that I'm using old-style C pointers. Could multi-threading be a problem? Or could the pointer ID be truncated when converted to `jlong`?

I also want to note that from my previous experience, I'm aware that the log is only a rough indicator of where a segmentation fault occurred. It may as well have been occurred later in the code and the next log message was simply not printed yet. However, reproducing this error may take 1-2 days, so I'd like to check out whether these lines have a problem.

Comment: A `jlong` is 64 bits so pointer truncation is not an issue. You mention multithreading – is `handles` protected sufficiently from race conditions?

Comment: The code you show may be where the problem becomes apparent. In and of itself, it is not the problem though. For a start, isolate the issue into a [mcve] and include a backtrace of the error.

Comment: As @Botje suggested, if `handles.insert(handle)` is called concurrently from multiple threads that's probably your issue. std::set isn't thread-safe. Try protecting it with a mutex.

Comment: @Botje @m88 Thanks, that's a good point. `handles` is not protected. I'll try to remove that set and check whether the error still occurs.

Comment: If you can, post a full call stack from the thread that caused the segmentation fault.  You may also want to add some additional logging in the suspect code.  Be aware that if this is a race condition, adding logging may affect the timing enough that the problem either disappears - or becomes a lot worse.

Comment: @AndrewHenle At the time of writing this question, I had no stack trace. The code was running in a container and everything got lost except for the log. I was lucky yesterday evening and could reproduce this error in a fairly short time. Although, the error occurred at a different position, `handles.erase`, I am pretty confident now, that using `std::set` in a multi-threading scenario is the source of this issue. I am running more tests now without the set and check whether the application is stable now over long periods of time.

Comment: Using *any* mutable container without synchronization is prone to race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing my `std::set` from the code, the error did not occur anymore. Conclusion: `std::set` in multithreading must be protected to avoid unrecoverable crashes.