# Connect life time of C++ objects to Java object

Tags: c++, pointers, java-native-interface

I have a C++ library with objects and am using this in conjunction with Java over JNI. Ideally, I'd like to tie the life cycle of the C++ objects to their Java equivalents and make it controllable from Java. Important to note is that the application is multi-threaded, so the C++ objects are accessed from multiple threads, and that those objects aren't modified after their initial construction. My current implementation looks something like this:

```
struct Tree {
  int age = 0;
  std::string type;
}

typedef Tree* TreeHandle;

/*
 * Class:     com_example_Tree
 * Method:    initialize
 * Signature: ([Lcom/example/Tree;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_Tree_initialize
        (JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jobject j_tree) {
    auto tree_ptr = new Tree();
    return (jlong) tree_ptr;
}

/*
 * Class:     com_example_Tree
 * Method:    dispose
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_Tree_dispose
        (JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jlong j_tree_handle) {
    auto tree_ptr = reinterpret_cast<TreeHandle*>(j_tree_handle);
    delete tree_ptr;
}
```

My Java part then looks like this:

```
class Tree implements AutoClosable {
    static {
        System.load("/path/to/tree.so");
    }

    private long handle;

    public Tree() {
        this.handle = initialize();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        if (this.handle != 0) {
            this.close();
        }
    }

    @override
    public synchronized void close() {
        dispose(this.handle);
        this.handle = 0;
    }

    private static native long initialize();
    private static native void dispose();
}
```

However, the result is that I have some global objects floating around in memory that are only accessible via a C-style pointer. Is there a more modern way of achieving the same, i.e., using smart pointers or directly designing the C++ objects as members of the Java class?

Comment: FYI: `if (tree_ptr != nullptr)` is not necessary.  It is perfectly legal to `delete` a `nullptr`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any better way of doing this right now. But there's the ongoing [Project Panama](https://openjdk.org/projects/panama/) which aims to improve Java-native interop in the future.

Comment: `close()` needs to be `syncrhonized` and `handle` needs to be set to `0` after `dispose()` is called else your object is not thread-safe.  It can also be useful to provide a Java `finalize()` method to clean up any native objects if your object happens to be used in ways where `close()` doesn't get called before the Java object gets garbage collected (or Cleaners if you're guaranteed to be Java 9+).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, I changed the code accordingly. We're currently still at Java 8, so cleaners aren't an option, but good to know that there's an alternative to `finalize` in later versions.

Comment: If you prefer smart pointers, you can keep a `std::map<size_t, std::shared_ptr<Tree>> trees` somewhere global and give the Java side just the `size_t` key.

Comment: @Botje I also thought about that solution, but as far as I know `std::map` isn't thread-safe by itself. I'd probably have to lock the regions where I modify the map to protect the application from simultaneously modifying the same key in two different threads? [similar to `std::set`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70461138/rare-segmentation-fault-during-object-creation-with-new)